# I set ANDROID_NDK_HOME but it keep says not set correctly

Tags: android-ndk, mediapipe

```
pedrojung@pedroui-MacBookPro MediaPipeUnityPlugin-master2 % echo $ANDROID_HOME                                      
/Users/pedrojung/Library/Android/sdk
pedrojung@pedroui-MacBookPro MediaPipeUnityPlugin-master2 % echo $ANDROID_NDK_HOME
/Users/pedrojung/Library/Android/sdk/ndk
```

what is weird is that
on setting android_ndk_home

```
pedrojung@pedroui-MacBookPro MediaPipeUnityPlugin-master2 % export ANDROID_NDK_HOME =/Users/pedrojung/Library/Android/sdk/ndk
zsh: /Users/pedrojung/Library/Android/sdk/ndk not found
```

it says idk folder is not found but it exist.
anyway, echo command says ANDROID_NDK_HOME is set.

ANDROID_NDK_HOME is located just same folder of ANDROID_HOME with only difference of idk folder...

error is.

```
Analysis of target '//mediapipe_api:mediapipe_proto_srcs' failed; build aborted: Could not read RELEASE.TXT in Android NDK: /Users/pedrojung/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/RELEASE.TXT (No such file or directory) Unable to read the Android NDK at /Users/pedrojung/Library/Android/sdk/ndk, the path may be invalid. Is the path in android_ndk_repository() or ANDROID_NDK_HOME set correctly? If the path is correct, the contents in the Android NDK directory may have been modified.
```

from above error , I can get android_ndk is not set correctly.
how can I set android_ndk correctly...?

I'm using m1 MacBook.

ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ

```
pedrojung@pedroui-MacBookPro MediaPipeUnityPlugin-master2 % cd $ANDROID_NDK_HOME
pedrojung@pedroui-MacBookPro ndk % ls
21.4.7075529    22.1.7171670    23.0.7599858
```

I checked path again, and yes it really has ndk.
and I installed ndk through android studio 's SDK manager.

Comment: A couple of things to try.   `cd $ANDROID_SDK_HOME` - make sure the android SDK is really there. `cd $ANDROID_NDK_HOME` make sure the NDK is there. If you get "No such file or directory" you've learned something.   Are you sure the NDK is installed? It's separate from the Android SDK and not installed by default.

Comment: pedrojung@pedroui-MacBookPro MediaPipeUnityPlugin-master2 % cd $ANDROID_NDK_HOME
pedrojung@pedroui-MacBookPro ndk % ls
21.4.7075529 22.1.7171670 23.0.7599858

yes NDK is just there 

NDK is installed through android studio ...and I did it.